# Finding what library files I need to include for the implementation of a particular c header

Tags: c, header, linker, compilation

How do I find what library files I need to include for the implementation of a particular c header if there is not library with the same name?

Comment: Why are you putting `#include<AHeaderIKnowNothingAbout>` in your code anyway?

Comment: It seems to have the function I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd Google for the name of the header or the functions within it.

If you're on a Debian-based system you could also try `dpkg -S <full header path>` to tell you what package provided the header, then see what other files (in `/usr/lib`) that same package provides.

Comment: This is an internal project so it wouldn't be googalable or be packaged as a deb.

Comment: Then you should search your internal documentation, using whatever internal tools your coworkers use.  If there is no such documentation or tooling, it might be time to make some.  If the headers got onto the systems by some mechanism other than the system package manager, you could query that system (why do I think there's really no system, and somebody just copied the files?).  You could guess that a .h file would have a matching .c file, and grep for its name in your build system.  If none of that works, ask your coworkers, and then try to make it better for the next person.

Comment: I ran locate for the .c file and didn't find it. I was hoping to some explanation maybe using strings or some tool to extract function names from libraries.

Comment: But you said you are searching for the library, no?  I guess if you have a candidate set of libraries and want to see which one contains a given symbol, you could dump their contents with `objdump` or similar and then use `grep`.